# Replace even numbers from the list that are multiples of 3 with factorials

Tags: python, list

Good afternoon, I can say new to programming
The task is this: the user must enter a list, and it must be sorted in ascending order. further even numbers and simultaneously multiples of 3, are replaced by factorials. Please help me figure it out. The way I did is wrong

```
import math

a = list(input("Enter a list: "))

print( sorted(a))

for x in a:
    if x%2 == 0:
        a[x] == a[math.factorial(x)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that by *even numbers and simultaneously multiples of 3* you mean that the numbers are multiples of 3 and 2.

Use [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html?highlight=ast%20literal_eval#ast.literal_eval) to convert the string list to a list, use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) for iterating over the list.

`if x%2 == 0 and x%3==0` can also be replaced by `x%6 == 0` as divisibility of 6 is if `x` is divisible by 2 and 3.

You cannot directly convert the input to a list because it will contain only  1 element - the value returned by `input`

```
import math
import ast
a = input("Enter a list: ")

a=sorted(list(ast.literal_eval(a)))

for b,x in enumerate(a):
    if x%2 == 0 and x%3==0:
        a[b] = math.factorial(x)
```

Output:

```
Enter a list: 1,4,3,6,5,3,12,18
[1, 3, 3, 4, 5, 720, 479001600, 6402373705728000]
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing `a[x]` where x is the value, you need to index the list and replace the value on that index as below:

```
for idx, x in enumerate(a):
    if x%2 == 0 or x%3==0:
        a[idx] == a[math.factorial(x)]
```

Comment: Your solution is almost the same as the other

Answer (score 0):

You can't convert an `input` result(which is actually a `string`) to list directly.

First make sure the separators of your input are the same, like  (space) or `,`. Then use `str.split` to split elements out.

The elements are `str` now so transform them to numbers by loop and then sort them.

For example:

```py
a = input("Enter a list: ").split(' ')
a = sorted([int(n) for n in a])
```

Then do your math trick.